# Mismatch between manpage and kernel behavior about getsockname

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I've experienced a smashing stack (= buffer overflow) problem recently when trying to run `iperf3`. I pinpointed the reason to the `getsockname()` call (https://github.com/esnet/iperf/blob/master/src/net.c#L463) that makes the kernel copy more data (`sizeof(sin_addr)`) at the designed address (`&sa`) than the size of the variable on the stack at that address.
`getsockname()` redirects the call to `getname()` (`AF_INET` family) :
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/af_inet.c#L698

If I believe the manpage (ubuntu) it says:

```c
int getsockname(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

> The `addrlen` argument should be initialized to indicate the amount of space (in bytes) pointed to by `addr`.  On return it contains the actual size of the socket address.
>
> The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small; in this case, `addrlen` will return a value greater than was supplied to the call.

But in the previous code excerpt, `getname()` does not care about the `addrlen` input value and uses the parameter as an output value only.

I had found a link (can't find it anymore) saying that BSD respects the previous manpage excerpt contrary to linux.

Am I missing something? I find it awkward that the documentation would be that much off, I've checked other linux `XXX_getname` calls and all I saw didn't care about the input length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

I believe that the `addrlen` value is not checked in kernel just to not waste some CPU cycles, because it should always be of known type (e.g. `struct sockaddr`), therefore it should always has known and fixed size (which is 16 bytes). So kernel just rewrites `addrlen` to 16, no matter what.

Regarding the issue you are having: I'm not sure why it's happening, but it doesn't actually seem that it's about size mismatch. I'm pretty sure kernel and userspace both have the same size of that structure which should be passed to `getsockname()` syscall (proof is below). So basically the situation you are describing here:

> ...that makes the kernel copy more data (sizeof(sin_addr)) at the designed address (&sa) than the size of the variable on the stack at that address

is not the case. I could only imagine how many application would fail if it was true.

## Detailed explanation

#### Userspace side

In `iperf` sources you have next definition of `sockaddr` struct (`/usr/include/bits/socket.h`):

```c
/* Structure describing a generic socket address.  */
struct sockaddr
  {
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sa_);    /* Common data: address family and length.  */
    char sa_data[14];           /* Address data.  */
  };
```

And `__SOCKADDR_COMMON` macro defined as follows (`/usr/include/bits/sockaddr.h`):

```c
/* This macro is used to declare the initial common members
   of the data types used for socket addresses, `struct sockaddr',
   `struct sockaddr_in', `struct sockaddr_un', etc.  */

#define __SOCKADDR_COMMON(sa_prefix) \
  sa_family_t sa_prefix##family
```

And `sa_family_t` defined as:

```c
/* POSIX.1g specifies this type name for the `sa_family' member.  */
typedef unsigned short int sa_family_t;
```

So basically `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` is always 16 bytes (= `sizeof(char[14])` + `sizeof(short)`).

#### Kernel side

In `inet_getname()` function you see that `addrlen` param is rewritten by next value:

```c
*uaddr_len = sizeof(*sin);
```

where `sin` is:

```c
DECLARE_SOCKADDR(struct sockaddr_in *, sin, uaddr);
```

So you see that `sin` has type of `struct sockaddr_in *`. This structure is defined as follows (`include/uapi/linux/in.h`):

```c
/* Structure describing an Internet (IP) socket address. */
#define __SOCK_SIZE__     16             /* sizeof(struct sockaddr)    */
struct sockaddr_in {
    __kernel_sa_family_t  sin_family;    /* Address family             */
    __be16                sin_port;      /* Port number                */
    struct in_addr        sin_addr;      /* Internet address           */

    /* Pad to size of `struct sockaddr'. */
    unsigned char         __pad[__SOCK_SIZE__ - sizeof(short int) -
              sizeof(unsigned short int) - sizeof(struct in_addr)];
};
```

So `sin` variable is also 16 bytes long.

## UPDATE

I'll try to reply to your comment:

> if getsockname wants to allocate an ipv6 instead that may be why it overflows the buffer

When calling `getsockname()` for `AF_INET6` socket, kernel will figure (in [getsockname()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c#L1562) syscall, by `sockfd_lookup_light()` function) that [inet6_getname()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv6/af_inet6.c#L439) should be called to handle your request. In that case, `uaddr_len` will be assigned with next value:

```c
struct sockaddr_in6 *sin = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)uaddr;
...    
*uaddr_len = sizeof(*sin);
```

So if you are using `sockaddr_in6` struct in your user-space program too, the size will be the same. Of course, if your userspace application is passing `sockaddr` structure to `getsockname` for `AF_INET6` socket, there will be some sort of overflow (because `sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)` > `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`). But I believe it's not the case for `iperf3` tool you are using. And if it is -- it's `iperf` that should be fixed in the first place, and not the kernel.

Comment: if getsockname wants to allocate an ipv6 instead that may be why it  overflows the buffer. I also guess it is about CPU cycles though I would like to be sure. A good practice may be to always call getsockname with a sockaddr_storage in that case. I reported this https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104601

Comment: I added **UPDATE** section to my answer regarding `ipv6` issue you were referring to.

Comment: was waiting for it thanks. This is still a bug in the documentation though and depending on what posix says it may be a *bug* in the kernel as well, don't want to check though.